# Crime in Solitude = huge bounty in Riften?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Here's the scenario: I was doing the 'Bound Until Death' quest for the Dark Brotherhood, and unlike my first playthrough, I actually got attacked by the guards, and got a bounty for killing the bride and the guards.  I encountered another guard at the entrance of Solitude, and he demanded I pay my bounty of 1040 gold.  Which I did.

At this point, instead of going back to the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary, I fast travelled to Riften to complete a quest, but upon entering the town after my fast travel, I was confronted by a guard that demanded I pay my bounty (9040 gold this time).

Mind you, I had committed no crimes to anyone's knowledge in Riften.  There was no reason for the bounty that I know of, and can't tell why this happened.

Currently I'm trying to decide if I want to just continue (I payed half my bounty, because I'm a thieve's guild member), or if I want to go back and try the Dark Brotherhood quest again to see if I can get a different result.

Can anyone explain why this might have happened?  I'm thinking glitch, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What makes you so sure that the bounty from Solitude is linked to the one in Riften? There are bugs that can make your follower go off and do things that incur bounties when you're not watching and other things like that. You may have incurred the bounty without realising it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's linked, and I didn't see this listed anywhere as a question here, so I asked.  You know, to find out if anyone else had run into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Dawnguard?  Fort Dawnguard is in The Rift, so any action taken against the Fort will get you a bounty in Riften. (Just as any action against Castle Volkahir will incur a Haafingar (Solitude) bounty.)
Also, to help you answer this better, if you didn't already know, 9040 bounty is assault and 9 counts of murder, perhaps that'll help you figure things out a bit easier, because now you've got me curious... lol.

Comment: I don't have any of the dlc, but I think you may be onto something there.  Perhaps because of WHO I killed, the bounty was for Riften and not Solitude.  This requires more research.  Thanks.